Firebase Auth status on Quest 2: "Unavailable invalid"
I'm having trouble starting Firebase on Meta Quest 2. The app builds without errors and the message that should appear in the FirebaseAuth dependencyStatus is: "available". However, when starting it on Quest 2, the following message appears: "unavailable invalid"
"Available" status occurs normally on Windows, Unity editor and Android phone. Does anyone know why this error occurs on Quest 2?
I tried rewriting the code, reinstalling the SDKs, setting up another Firebase account, checked the package name, checked Google services json, tried options related to internet connection. But the dependencyStatus remains "unavailable invalid".
This is the code:
async void Start()
{
    Debug.Log("Checking dependencies");
    await FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
    {
        dependencyStatus = task.Result;         
    });
    Debug.Log("Logging");
    var auth = FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance;
    await auth.SignInAnonymouslyAsync();
    Debug.Log("Logged!");
    auth.SignOut();
    Debug.Log("Unlogged!");
 }


Which Firebase products other than Auth are you using? Do you retrieve any additional error logs on uploading to the Meta Quest storefront?

I'm not using any other firebase product, just Auth. I also didn't have additional error logs on uploading to the Meta Quest.
I have already tested with the updated version (for Unity) of the FirebaseAuth SDK 12.1 (API Level 34, 33), and with 11.9.0 (API Level 32) and 11.6.0 (API Level 31).
The dependencyStatus keeps showing "Unvailable invalid"
The strange thing is that it works on windows, unity editor and android phone. Doesn't just work on Quest 2.

Hello again, we finally solved the problem! Although the application is for Android, all you had to do was install the IOS support build on Unity for Firebase to work and be available!
In build.gradle it was used:
minSdkVersion 23
targetSdkVersion 33
compileSdkVersion 34
and it worked. Thanks for helping
